# Is it possible to make HTML Purifier to replace double <br> with <p> and at the same time not to delete single one?

Tags: php, html, htmlpurifier

Is it possible to make HTML Purifier to replace double `<br>` with `<p>` and at the same time not to delete single one? How easy it is to make?

We are trying to change double `<br>` into `<p>` in user genereated content and we use HTML Purifier for this purpose. But it seems this library cuts out all single `<br>` at the same time.

p.s. I am not a programmer, I am a product manager. And I asked to configure the text parser (we use HTML Purifier) on our service to let it use tags `<p>` insted of `<br><br>` in user generated texts. The programmer has done this but the next problem arises: the parser begins to cut out single line break `<br>`. And I was told that it is impossible or very hard to fix it. I am confused, I worked with regular expressions before and this was not a problem at all.

Comment: Can you please update your question to show us what you have done / tried so far?

Comment: You can do this with a regular expression match/replace. No need for html purifier to do this.

Comment: @OleHaugset I am not a programmer, I am a product manager. And I asked to configure the text parser (we use HTML Purifier) on our service to let it use tags <p> insted of <br><br> in user generated texts. The programmer has done this but the next problem arises: the parser begins to cut out single line break <br>. And I was told that it is impossible or very hard to fix it.

And I am confused. I worked with regular expressions before and this was not  a problem at all.

Answer (score -2):

It can be done pretty easy. The first (and definitely most easy method) is just to replace `<br><br>` with `</p><p>` and wrap the whole content in `<p></p>` tags.

```
$string = str_replace( '<br><br>', '</p><p>', $string );
$string = str_replace( '<br /><br />', '</p><p>', $string );
$string = str_replace( '<br><br />', '</p><p>', $string );
$string = str_replace( '<br /><br>', '</p><p>', $string );
echo "<p>$string</p>";
```

But a more cleaner solution is this. Use regex to identify the tags and then do a replace. It searches for `<br>,<br >,<br />, etc.` and then does a replace. Like so:

```
function replace_br($data) {
    $data = preg_replace('#(?:<br\s*/?>\s*?){2,}#', '</p><p>', $data);
    return "<p>$data</p>";
}
```

Info found here: [php: replacing double <br /> with </p><p>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959734/php-replacing-double-br-with-pp)